# In which scenario we need to create a new thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have doubts about when we need to create a single thread in Asp.Net?
I am new in programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure this is phrased properly. There are many good reasons to make a new thread (in C# and other languages), we could fill the site with listing them all. Are you encountering any specifically that you are unsure about?

Answer (score 4):

The presentation layer in a web app usually doesn't need to create extra threads itself. ASP.NET will manage threads (sometimes in surprising ways - it's *thread agile*, so you can find that a single request is handled my more than one thread in the course of its lifetime) for you.

Things are reasonably simple if you're writing a web app which can deal with each request in a synchronous (blocking) way - it gets more complicated if you need to write "long-polling" apps where you might expect tens or hundreds of thousands of simultaneous connections, all waiting for an event-based response. C# 5 and VB 11 will make that simpler with the new async features.

Usually threads are more likely to be created in layers *lower* than the presentation layer, possibly running as separate Windows services, although possibly for web services still running in ASP.NET. Even there, however, it's worth trying to avoid the complications of multi-threading unless you really need them.

"Rich" client applications (WPF, WinForms, Silverlight) are *much* more likely to need threads or at least some form of asynchrony, as they need to keep the UI thread free to handle UI events, while they may have some background processing (whether that's local CPU-bound work or possibly loading files from the disk or network) to do.

Answer (score 2):

As you are new in programming, here's a simplified truth for you: **never**. You never have to create new threads in ASP.NET.

When you gain more experience, you'll learn about advanced techniques.

Comment: But if i don't create a thread. It throws error:"ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.". How to avoid the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you need to run a background/separate (from application) task you may need to create a separate thread (out of the application boundary), integration usually done via common databases. 
In ASP.NET usually done with services running on servers, for example a service that sends email notifications to users etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is usefull to me.